# Drawing up a hexadecimal number from several decimal numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm, hex, decimal

I have a vector container. There are a number from 0 to 255. The data bytes are top (of the container). On the fourth day begins mantissa and it may consist of several numbers, for example. Mantissa consists of <120, 111, 200>. That is, it is the number of machine: <0x78, 0x6F, 0xC8>. Total turn mantissa: **0x786FC8**.

> I can convert because of the method:
>
> 1. Set the number of 120, 111, 200 in hexadecimal.(0x78, 0x6F, 0xC8)
> 2. Put the numbers in line.("78" "6F" "C8")
> 3. Fold the line.("786FC8")
> 4. Move back to an integer type. 0x786FC8

**Q: Is there any way you do it faster and without strings?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want <*120*, *111*, *200*> → `(120 * 256 + 111) * 256 + 200`.

Comment: Yes I do and need is a formula that?

Comment: @user3274299: Yes, that is the formula.

Comment: And what a reverse algorithm? If I need to convert 7892936 to <120, 111, 200>?