# Translation of number systems

Tags: c++, algorithm, int, decimal

I have three numbers in decimal form, they make itself one more decimal number. <120, 111, 200> - (120 * 256 + 111) * 256 + 200 = 7892936 - Decimal. I keep the number is because I have a variable number of bytes to write the number.

> **Q:** How can I carry out the reverse operation?? If I need to convert
>   7892936 to <120, 111, 200>?

[Drawing up a hexadecimal number from several decimal numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315623/drawing-up-a-hexadecimal-number-from-several-decimal-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to do modulus and divide in similar order:

```
int val = 7892936;
while(val > 0){
    int mod = val%256;
    print mod;
    val /= 256;
}
```

So the result will be:

```
200
111
120
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use bitmask and right-shift. Following may help:

```
std::array<std::uint8_t, 4> convert(std::uint32_t u)
{
    return {
         (u >> 24) & 0xFF,
         (u >> 16) & 0xFF,
         (u >>  8) & 0xFF,
         u & 0xFF
    };
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/KUgwU0)

Answer (score 1):

Use repeated modulo and division operations in a loop for generic integer radix conversion. Optimizations for specific bases are possible, but shouldn't really concern you yet.

Also, you probably don't have numbers in decimal form. You have numbers. Unless you store them as strings, it's up to the computer to store them, and it will store them as binary.

Answer (score 1):

```
int bigNumber = 7892936;
int a = bigNumber & FF;
int b = (bigNumber & FF00) >> 8;
int c = (bigNumber & FF0000) >> 16;
```

Answer (score 1):

perform AND with ff, ff00, and ff0000 respectively.